Are there any strict aliasing rule violations that are not detected by -Wstrict-aliasing?
I created a function that copies strings quickly by copying 8 bytes at a time, similar to the built-in memcpy. In the following function, the char pointer type is cast to an unsigned long long pointer type and referenced.
However, I later wondered if this might violate the strict aliasing rule. I compiled it with the cc -O2 -Wstrict-aliasing command, and there were no warnings, and the program worked correctly. Isn't this a violation of the strict aliasing rule, or is it a violation of the strict aliasing rule that cannot be detected with the -Wstrict-aliasing option?
char    *my_strncpy(char *dst, char *src, size_t n) {
    char    *first_dst;
    char    *last_src;

    first_dst = dst;
    last_src = src + n - 1;
    while (src + 7 <= last_src)
    {
        *(unsigned long long*)dst = *(unsigned long long*)src;
        dst += 8;
        src += 8;
    }
    while (src <= last_src)
    {
        *dst = *src;
        dst++;
        src++;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
    return (first_dst);
}

int main(void)
{
    char    dst[100];
    char    src[100] = "012345678901234567890123456789";

    my_strncpy(dst, src, 20);
    printf("%s\n", dst);
    return (0);
}


The problem is that char* doubles as "address of a memory byte", and the cast is correct if there actually is an unsigned long long stored at that address. How is the compiler to know?

Also, have you checked the generated code? Some compilers will see what you are doing, and call memcpy anyway! See the talk here: Matt Godbolt “What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately?"

The 64-bit values may need to be 8-byte aligned, but you've only dealt with the partial bytes at the end, not the beginning to ensure alignment.

The compiler is not able to cactch all possible cases

@WeatherVane at the beginning too

@BoP Thank you for your comment! You mean ~, a compiler analyzes each function individually, so it is difficult to completely track the usage of types that span multiple functions, right?

@0___________ I don't understand your comment directed to me. Was it not clear that I was suggesting that some bytes may need to be written at the beginning and/or at the end? Those at the start, for alignment as I mentioned, those at the end for the residue... "only dealt with the partial bytes at the end, not the beginning to ensure alignment."

Your code will fail on any architecture which does not support unaligned access.

You do not copy strings as you never check for null terminating charackter. Your function does the same as memcpy but not strncpy.

This particular warning could best be described as buggy and unreliable.

@akyoshid - Compilers can analyze cross-function code, especially when inlining, but they don't have to. Code that is sometimes right and sometimes wrong might not always get caught (especially if you do "unusual" things).


Are there any strict aliasing rule violations that are not detected by -Wstrict-aliasing?

Yes, of course. First, the documentation says there are:

… The warning does not catch all cases,…

Second, it is impossible for the compiler to detect cases it cannot see: If you define an object as long in one translation unit and use it as double in another translation unit, the compiler cannot see when compiling the latter that the type is wrong.

In the following function, the char pointer type is cast to an unsigned long long pointer type and referenced.

The char pointer type is irrelevant. What matters is the effective type of the memory it points to. The aliasing rules are not defined in terms of the types of pointers used prior to the last pointer type. (The last pointer type matters because, when you apply * or […] to dereference it, it sets the lvalue type, which is part of the aliasing rules.)
If the memory was originally defined with some type (versus dynamically allocated with malloc), then that type is its effective type, and the fact it was passed via char * does not change how it may or may not be aliased.

However, I later wondered if this might violate the strict aliasing rule.

Yes, it does, unless the char * points to memory with an effective type that may be aliased by unsigned long long.

And even if there was only one translation unit, detecting strict aliasing violations at compile-time is an undecidable problem and potentially input-dependent. So either there must be (many) false positives or false negatives.

@eric-postpischil Thanks to you, I was able to gain knowledge about effective type. I appreciate your answer & kindness!
